# Cannot add item to array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I add a new item to an array? I'm trying to add an item but it returns an error. Please see my screenshot below and my code.

**Screenshot**
[image]

**JavaScript Code**

```
var roles = [{id: 8, display_name: "test", description: "test", created_at: "2020-02-20 11:34:22", updated_at: "2020-02-20 11:34:22"}
8: {id: 9, display_name: "ASDASD", description: "ADASD", created_at: "2020-02-20 11:39:08", updated_at: "2020-02-20 11:39:08"}
9: {id: 10, display_name: "Test1", description: "test1", created_at: "2020-02-20 11:44:01", updated_at: "2020-02-20 11:44:01"}
10: {id: 11, display_name: "Test2", description: "test2", created_at: "2020-02-21 04:18:49", updated_at: "2020-02-21 04:18:49"}
11: {id: 12, display_name: "Test3", description: "test3", created_at: "2020-02-21 06:56:52", updated_at: "2020-02-21 06:56:52"}
12: {id: 13, display_name: "Test4", description: "test4", created_at: "2020-02-21 07:00:32", updated_at: "2020-02-21 07:00:32"}];


this.roles.id = 12;
this.roles.display_name = 'Mod';
this.roles.description = 'mod';
this.roles.created_at = '2020-02-21 07:12:50';
this.roles.updated_at = '2020-02-21 07:12:50';
```

**Error**

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined

**What I want**:

Add item to the data from the screenshot above.

**Note**

I'm using vueJS, and I have set the `roles` data inside of `data{}` object.

Comment: what are you doing? what error do you get? please add your code.

Comment: Hi @NinaScholz please see my update.

Comment: What you have is an array of objects. JSON is a data exchange format like YAML or CSV. You might want to [read up on Arrays on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: Why are you using `this.roles` instead of `roles`?

Comment: @FelixKling sorry I forgot to mention that it is inside of `data{}` object. I'm using vuejs here. Please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `this.roles` is probably the array of items you're logging, right?

So by setting `this.roles.id = 12;`, you're trying to set an `id` property of the array, not add a new item to the array with those properties.

Try this

```
var newRole = {
  id: 12,
  display_name: 'Mod',
  description: 'mod',
  created_at: '2020-02-21 07:12:50',
  updated_at: '2020-02-21 07:12:50'
};

this.roles.push(newRole);
```

That's my best guess. You really should upload more info about the problem though:

- What are you logging in that screenshot?
- What about your current approach doesn't work?

Comment: I tried it just now, and I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` error.

Comment: @Jonjie: Your code example looks incomplete. What does `this` refer to?

Comment: `this.roles` is not available. Since he's not in an `object`, `this` will return the `window` object, and there is not a `roles` attribute in it.

Comment: @Refilon: There will be if `roles` is a global variable.

Comment: @FelixKling but in the example it's not.

Comment: @FelixKling I think I'm not accessing the `role` variable. It is not accessible I think

Comment: @Refilon: Based on the error message I agree with you. I guess it doesn't even matter what the context is, they should just use `roles` to reference the variable directly. A more complete example would be nice though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution,
I've created your sample role array of objects,
Created a new object to be added,
 
and then added the new object to the array.

```
let roles = [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "display_name" : "One",
        "description" : "One desc",
        "created_at" : "2020-02-21 01:01:01",
        "updated_at" : "2020-02-21 01:01:01"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "display_name" : "Two",
        "description" : "Two desc",
        "created_at" : "2020-02-21 01:01:01",
        "updated_at" : "2020-02-21 01:01:01"
    }
];

let newRole = {};
newRole.id = 3;
newRole.display_name = "Three";
newRole.description = "Three desc";
newRole.created_at = "2020-02-21 01:01:01";
newRole.updated_at = "2020-02-21 01:01:01";

roles.push(newRole);
```

You are directly trying to add an object into the array,
You can do that as well if you specify the index

Answer (score 1):

This is an array of json elements. You need to make an element first and then push it in the array of roles like this.

```
let newElement = {id:12, display_name :'Mod', description : 'mod', created_at:'2020-02-21 07:12:50', updated_at:'2020-02-21 07:12:50'}
this.roles.push(newElement)
```

Comment: *"This is an array of json elements."* It's an array of objects. There is no JSON here. JSON is a textual data exchange format.

Comment: `this.roles` is not available. Since he's not in an `object`, this will return the `window` object, and there is not a `roles` attribute in it.

Answer (score 0):

You got undefined error since your using "this" which refers to the window and not to the object.

You can add it manually as you already got the answers for it or you can use Class instead which in my opinion will work way better, I don't think that using all those code copying is good, that's my solution:

```
const roles = [{ id: 8, display_name: "test", description: "test", created_at: "2020-02-20 11:34:22", updated_at: "2020-02-20 11:34:22" },
{ id: 9, display_name: "ASDASD", description: "ADASD", created_at: "2020-02-20 11:39:08", updated_at: "2020-02-20 11:39:08" },
{ id: 10, display_name: "Test1", description: "test1", created_at: "2020-02-20 11:44:01", updated_at: "2020-02-20 11:44:01" },
{ id: 11, display_name: "Test2", description: "test2", created_at: "2020-02-21 04:18:49", updated_at: "2020-02-21 04:18:49" },
{ id: 12, display_name: "Test3", description: "test3", created_at: "2020-02-21 06:56:52", updated_at: "2020-02-21 06:56:52" },
{ id: 13, display_name: "Test4", description: "test4", created_at: "2020-02-21 07:00:32", updated_at: "2020-02-21 07:00:32" }];

class Role {
    id;
    display_name;
    description;
    created_at;
    updated_at;
    constructor(id, display_name, description, created_at, updated_at) {
        this.id = id;
        this.display_name = display_name;
        this.description = description;
        this.created_at = created_at;
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
    }
}

const role1 = new Role(14, "asdas", "asdasd", "2020-02-21", "2020-02-21");
roles.push(role1);
const role2 = new Role(15, "asdasas", "assdasd", "2020-02-21", "2020-02-21");
roles.push(role2);
```